# Gremlin text search or indexing on the subgraph

Tags: graph, cassandra, gremlin, graph-databases, janusgraph

I am trying to develop the solution for file sharing/permissions using graph database.
The challange I faced with is how to implement full-text search for certain fields like name, extension, date, etc.
[image: Graph structure]

This is what I think the graph is.
When user2 searches **Folder** - hew should be able to see what is shared with him + his own files matching the name. Elliptical shape represents what I think should be the limit of search - if I understand it right it would be inefficient to search the whole vertices index by the name and after that filter by the owner/access.

So the question is - is there a way to search the subgraph of the graph using gremlin? Preferably in Janusgraph(+Cassandra). Or is there a better practice for such? Maybe to store the full list of files in the client(updates via Websocket) and perform the local search on flat structure?

Comment: In what way are traditional file system permissions (owner-group-world) insufficient for your usecase?  Also, full text search means finding tokens in a larger piece of text, while you want just to match strings?